# ocaml type within a type

Tags: types, ocaml, records

If I have a type in a module State

```
type state = {x: int; y: int}
```

and I have another type in module Game

```
type game = State.state
```

how can I access the record values in a object with type game?

For example if I have a game "g", g.x gives me an "Unbound record field label x" error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The names of the fields are in the `State` module namespace. You can say `g.State.x`, or you can open the `State` module.

```
let f g = g.State.x
```

Or:

```
open State

let f g = g.x
```

If you want the fields to appear in the `Game` module namespace, you can repeat them:

```
type game = State.state = {x: int; y: int}
```

You can also  use the `include` facility to include the `State` module.

For example, your `Game` module could say:

```
include State
type game = state
```

In either of these cases, you can refer to `Game.x`:

```
let f g = g.Game.x
```

Or:

```
open Game
let f g = g.x
```

There are also two notations for opening a module for just a single expression:

```
let f g = Game.(g.x)
```

Or:

```
let f g = let open Game in g.x
```

**Edit:**  Here's a Unix command-line session that shows the first (simplest) solution:

```
$ cat state.ml
type state = { x: int; y : int }
$ cat game.ml
type game = State.state
$ cat test.ml
let f (g: Game.game) = g.State.x

let () = Printf.printf "%d\n" (f { State.x = 3; y = 4})
$ ocamlc -o test state.ml game.ml test.ml
$ ./test
3
```

Comment: hmm none of those seem to work...if I try g.State.x it says "Unbound record field label State.x" and inserting open State does not change anything

Comment: I tested them all, so they work for me. I assumed each module was a file: state.ml, game.ml, and test.ml. Need to compile state.ml, then game.ml, then test.ml.

Comment: I have mli files for game and state, would that affect their interaction in any way?

Comment: The mli files need to define the symbols you want to use, that's really the essence. If some symbols aren't in there, then they won't be defined. For my simple example, the mli files will be identical to the ml files! But for real code, they'll be different of course.

Comment: @Mike: the mli files define the visibility of your types and values

Comment: The last 2 notations are available only starting from ver. 3.12 of OCaml.